# How to save an XML file on server with Haxe PHP?

Tags: php, haxe

I am just starting out with Haxe development, and wanted to give the PHP side a go, but am already a little confused.

What is the best way to save some form data to XML files in a folder on a server with Haxe compiled to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do it two ways.
Make the website form in haxe, which includes:

making proper .htaccess file for the project on server,

writting a Main class (that htaccess will be pointing) which will take a request,
and return either a form html document or will take the data from the form...

then put that data into xml format,
and finally put that data into a file.

Here are Api files you should have a look at:

[File methods for writting to a file](http://haxe.org/api/php/io/file)

[Web class that will get request data and fire up proper class and function, getURI, getMethod, getParams](http://haxe.org/api/php/web)

[Template class for generating simple html / very simple](http://haxe.org/api/haxe/template?lang=en)

[Depending on complexity of xml you may want to use a specialized class](http://haxe.org/api/xml)

And the second way is almost the same, but you only compile to one file.
And in your html form, you put your action link to the php filed that came out of compilation...